# How do I specify to pip that it should only build wheels if they don't exist in the wheelhouse?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pip, python-wheel

So currently we have a build process that works like so:

```
#copy wheelhouse if it exists
if [[ -d $WHEELHOUSE ]]; then
        sudo cp -aTr $WHEELHOUSE $WORKSPACE/wheelhouse
fi

cd $WORKSPACE; pip install --find-links=$WORKSPACE/wheelhouse --use-wheel -r requirements-meta.txt; pip install --find-links=$WORKSPACE/wheelhouse --use-wheel -r requirements.txt; pip install --find-links=$WORKSPACE/wheelhouse --use-wheel -r requirements-dev.txt;

echo "Now building wheels"

pip wheel --wheel-dir=$WORKSPACE/wheelhouse --find-links $WORKSPACE/wheelhouse -r requirements-meta.txt; pip wheel --wheel-dir=$WORKSPACE/wheelhouse --find-links $WORKSPACE/wheelhouse -r requirements-dev.txt; pip wheel --wheel-dir=$WORKSPACE/wheelhouse --find-links $WORKSPACE/wheelhouse -r requirements.txt
```

This allows us to then copy over the wheelhouse with the rest of the workspace onto our production servers, and use those wheels as the install base for pip on those servers.

For some reason, this **always** builds wheels for numpy and scipy (as well as pycrypto and a few others, but those are less time-consuming), even if they already exist in `$WORKSPACE/wheelhouse`.

What we'd like to have happen is for pip wheel to skip building these wheels if they already exist in $WORKSPACE/wheelhouse. Is there something I'm missing on how to do this?